# Get the sum of leaves days until the search month

Tags: php, mysqli

I have leave details table in below structure.

```
emp_id     leave_from      leave_to     total_days
  1        2017-08-01     2017-08-04       3
  1        2017-09-10     2017-09-12       2
```

When i search the september, i want to dispaly total = 3 and when it is october month search, total = 5.

I tried below code. But it gives me the total sum for every month search.

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(total_days) as total FROM leave_details l WHERE l.emp_id='$empId' AND status=1 AND YEAR(l.leave_from)='$yearSearch' GROUP BY YEAR(l.leave_from)");

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4); 
  echo $row['total'];
```

Can someone assist me to solve the doubt??? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query using GROUP BY YEAR,

you need to change to using GROUP BY MONTH... and you will get list of sum total leavs by existing month for in this year

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(total_days) as total FROM leave_details l WHERE l.emp_id='$empId' AND status=1 AND YEAR(l.leave_from)='$yearSearch' GROUP BY MONTH(l.leave_from)");
```

and then you need to fetch list and iterate foreach ...

you can see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php for more info

```
while ($row = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['total'].'<br />';
}
```

if you want only scpecific year+month and get only 1 result,

try using this query

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(total_days) as total FROM leave_details l WHERE l.emp_id='$empId' AND status=1 AND YEAR(l.leave_from)='$yearSearch' AND MONTH(l.leave_from)")='$monthSearch';

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4); 
echo $row['total'];
```

If you want for specific year, until some month... just change the operator in MONTH part of the query... **< instead of =**

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SUM(total_days) as total FROM leave_details l WHERE l.emp_id='$empId' AND status=1 AND YEAR(l.leave_from)='$yearSearch' AND MONTH(l.leave_from)")<'$monthSearch';
```

Comment: Can you explain how to get the sum by iterating using foreach??

Comment: I edit toe post and added example and link for documantation.

Comment: It doesn't give the expected answer sir.

Comment: Sir, i want to add total leave days until the search month. If i search total leave days up to march, i want to calculate all the leave days in january and february. If i search august, i want to get the sum of leave days from jan to july. When i used your code it gives only the specific months total only.

Comment: add new query.. just change the operator  < instead of = in the WHERE MONTH part

Comment: you succeeded with the operator change?

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It works as I expected. Thanks again.:)